# In R, why does using do.call change the result?

Tags: r

For example, if I have a multidimensional list object, say, "x"

```
x <- list(); x[[1]] <- c(1,2,3); x[[2]] <- c(2,3,4); 
x[[3]] <- c(3,4,5); x[[4]] <- c(4,5,6)
a <- combn(x,3)
```

If I want to combine every row in the first column into a single vector, this doesn't give me what I want:

```
c(a[1:3,1]).
```

It returns a list with each element an element of the original list. Instead, this works:

```
do.call(c,a[1:3,1])
```

According to the help description, all do.call does is execute a function, so why is the result different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c(a[1:3,1])` is equivalent here to `a[1:3,1]` which is equivalent here to `a[1:3]`. All this does is combine the list, not combine the elements of this list.

`do.call` executes a function call against a list of arguments, in this case, it executes the `c` function to combine the elements of `a`.

What you want is `c(a[1:3], recursive = TRUE)`, which descends through the list recursively combining elements into a single vector.

Comment: Are you sure a[1:3, 1] = a[1:3]? I tried a[1:3,2] and it was different.

Comment: Yes, this is just an artifact of how you defined `a` in this case, and this is of little importance to the solution, just so you wouldn't wonder why I saved a keystroke three sentences later. It is easier to see how it works when you return a list, i.e., `a <- combn(x,3,simplify = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `do.call` is a list of arguments to pass to the function. So `do.call(c, a[1:3,1])` is equivalent to `c(a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]])`.

If you want to pass a list to `c` when using `do.call`, you need to put the list in a list: `do.call(c, list(a[1:3,1]))`.