# Understanding unlisting matrix using do.call

Tags: r, matrix, do.call

I was searching for some approaches to unlist matrices and I think the most efficient and simplest one is

`do.call(rbind, matrix_to_unlist)`. I tried it and it works but I have no idea why. `rbind()` function is designed to add a row to matrix/data frame so how is this possible to work ? Could you please explain to me what exactly `do.call()` is doing with `rbind()` function that in output we get matrix unlisted ?

Comment: It calls the internal function do.call to invoke it

Comment: But to invoke what ? rbind ? How calling rbind unlists matrix ??

Comment: THere are some links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801750/whats-the-difference-between-lapply-and-do-call) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863018/in-r-why-does-using-do-call-change-the-result) that could help you

Answer (score 0):

If you check the help file of do.call, it reads

> `do.call` constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
> function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

So, let suppose, you have

```
matrices_in_list <- list(matrix_a, matrix_b, ...)
```

so, when you run `do.call(rbind, matrices_in_list)`, then it is equivalent to:

```
rbind(matrix_a, matrix_b, ...)
```

You can call `cbind` to bind your matrices by column.